# Como cargar valores de una función en un select - Javascript - DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, select

Debo cargar los valores del `array` provincias en este `select` al recargar la página.

**Código HTML:**

```
<select name="provincia" id="provincia">
    <option value="cargar_provincias();">Seleccione una Provincia...
</select>
```

**Código JS:**

```
//Funcion para cargar las provincias al campo "select".
function cargarProvincias() {
    //Inicializamos el array.
    var array = ["Cantabria", "Asturias", "Galicia", "Andalucia", "Extremadura"];
    //Ordena el array alfabeticamente.
    array.sort();
    //Pasamos a la funcion addOptions(el ID del select, las provincias cargadas en el array).
    addOptions("provincia", array);
}


//Funcion para agregar opciones a un <select>.
function addOptions(domElement, array) {
    var selector = document.getElementsByName(domElement)[0];
    //Recorremos el array.
    for (provincia in array) {
        var opcion = document.createElement("option");
        opcion.text = array[provincia];
        selector.add(opcion);
    }
}
```

¿Por qué no se me cargan los valores al desplegar el select?

```
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    miformulario.provincia.addEventListener("keypress", function(){ 
        return cargarProvincias(event);
    }, false);
  });
```

Comment: En vez de `opcion.text = array[provincia];` no debería ser `opcion.text = provincia;` ?

Comment: Cierto, aún así, no funciona. Es cuestión de asociar el evento addEventListener con la función cargarProvincias.

Comment: Consulta: qué es `miformulario`?

Comment: el nombre del formulario <form>  <form name="miformulario" id="idmiformulario" onSubmit="return validar(this)">

Comment: Cambia el evento load por esto:  `window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        return cargarProvincias(event);
  });`

Comment: Sin probarlo, si imprimo eso me valen los valores de 0 a 4, no los nombres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No deberías de asignar un evento de `keypress` o cualquier otro tipo para esa funcionalidad, porque con eso sólo conseguirás que tu función se ejecute cada vez que se cumpla el evento y te agregue más y más provincias dando así resultados indeseados.

```js
miformulario = document.querySelector('#miFormulario');
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
         cargarProvincias(event);
    }, false);

//Funcion para cargar las provincias al campo "select".
function cargarProvincias() {
    //Inicializamos el array.
    var array = ["Cantabria", "Asturias", "Galicia", "Andalucia", "Extremadura"];
    //Ordena el array alfabeticamente.
    array.sort();
    //Pasamos a la funcion addOptions(el ID del select, las provincias cargadas en el array).
    addOptions("provincia", array);
}


//Funcion para agregar opciones a un <select>.
function addOptions(domElement, array) {
    var selector = document.getElementsByName(domElement)[0];
    //Recorremos el array.
    for (provincia in array) {
        var opcion = document.createElement("option");
        opcion.text = array[provincia];
        selector.add(opcion);
    }
}
```

```html
<form id='miFormulario'>
<select name="provincia" id="provincia">
    <option value="">Seleccione una Provincia...
</select>
</form>
```

Te dejo el ejemplo funcionando donde sólo cargas una vez las provincias.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en el evento `Load`.

Estás llamando `miforumlario.provincia` de manera incorrecta, además de que no es necesario.

El siguiente código llama al evento `cargarProvincias` directamente.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    cargarProvincias(event);
}, false);

//Funcion para cargar las provincias al campo "select".
function cargarProvincias() {
    //Inicializamos el array.
    var array = ["Cantabria", "Asturias", "Galicia", "Andalucia", "Extremadura"];
    //Ordena el array alfabeticamente.
    array.sort();
    //Pasamos a la funcion addOptions(el ID del select, las provincias cargadas en el array).
    addOptions("provincia", array);
}


//Funcion para agregar opciones a un <select>.
function addOptions(domElement, array) {
    var selector = document.getElementsByName(domElement)[0];
    //Recorremos el array.
    for (provincia in array) {
        var opcion = document.createElement("option");
        opcion.text = array[provincia];
        selector.add(opcion);
    }
}
```

```html
<select name="provincia" id="provincia">
    <option value="">Seleccione una Provincia...</option>
</select>
```